# Swiping is not working. How to resolve this?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am really beginner in iOS development.
I am doing a project like swiping the image.
1. Search for a component called Swipe Gesture Recognizer
2. Grab it and drop it on top of the View (use the hierarchy to make sure you drop it on it, if you drop it on another element this code will not work)
3. Select one of the Swipe Gesture Recognizer in the hierarchy and go to its attribute page. Change Swipe to Left.
4. Make sure the other recognizer has the Swipe attribute to Right
5. Select UIScrollView and uncheck Scrolling enabled
6. Connect detectSwipe() to both recognizers.

The above mentioned steps are my task but i can't achieve the step 6

I think the IBAction is not recoganized.

## This is my code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    // initialize UIImageView empty array
    var images  = [UIImageView]()

    let MAX_PAGE = 2
    let MIN_PAGE = 0
    var currentPage = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        var contentWidth: CGFloat = 0.0
        let scrollWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width

        for x in 0...2{
            let image = UIImage(named: "icon\(x).png")
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
            images.append(imageView)

            var newX: CGFloat = 0.0
            newX = scrollWidth / 2 + scrollWidth * CGFloat(x)

            contentWidth += newX

            scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: newX - 75, y: (scrollView.frame.size.height / 2) - 75, width: 150, height: 150)
        }

        self.images[self.currentPage].transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.4, y: 1.4)

        scrollView.clipsToBounds = false

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: view.frame.size.height)
    }



    @IBAction func detectSwipe(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

        if (currentPage < MAX_PAGE && sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left) {
            moveScrollView(direction: 1)

        }

        if (currentPage > MIN_PAGE && sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right) {
            moveScrollView(direction: -1)
        }
    }

    func moveScrollView(direction: Int){
        currentPage = currentPage + direction
        let point: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(currentPage), y: 0.0)
        scrollView.setContentOffset(point, animated: true)

        // Create a animation to increase the actual icon on screen
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4){
            self.images[self.currentPage].transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.4, y: 1.4)

            // Revert icon size of the non-active pages
            for x in 0..<self.images.count {
                if (x != self.currentPage) {
                    self.images[x].transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

## This is my view hierarchy

[image]

## Error not scrolling

[image]

Comment: Please explain little more what you want to acheive.

Answer (score 0):

Your Step 6 basically makes sure which method gets called when your gesture is recognized.
In your case you want your detectSwipe() method to get fired up.

There are many ways you can achieve this, easiest way is go to your view Hierarchy, Control+Drag from both of your "Swipe Gesture Recognizer" to the View Controller. Upon doing this you will see a small window listing out many options, one of them will be detectSwipe usually under Sent Actions. Select that.

If you are worried that IBAction is not recognized, a simple way to verify is go to where you defined you method(in your ViewController class) there you should be able to see a small bubble on the left side of your method name(in place where we usually put break points). This bubble confirms that this method can be used as a Target to any UI Action.

Please mark the answer as correct if it helps solve your problem, and please upvote if you got a correct solution, I'm new here :D

Comment: In that process sent Actions only connected but the Referencing Outlet Collections is not connected

Comment: Yes, correct. Thats all the Step 6 is doing "Connect detectSwipe() to both recognizers".

Comment: The Referencing Outlet would anyways be connected to "Swipe Gesture Recognizer" of View Hierarchy. Correct me if I am wrong. I might need more explanation on what connections have been made in IB and what you have done in the Project.

Comment: I am sorry but thats all the Step 6 does. You can verify that the connection has been established between the method and "Swipe Gesture Recognizer" of View Hierarchy, by showing both storyboard and Class using Assistant editor, and hover over the bubble in the detectSwipe() method.